# Как заставить срабатывать href#?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я использую якорь, и хочу иметь подсветку когда на якорь нажимают. Если скрипт отключить то подсветка срабатывает.

я так понимаю что это из за того что не добавляется в браузере /site.com/#test
как включить это добавление?

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
var target = $(this).attr('href');
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 250 }, 800);
return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j9knzuh1/40/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `window.location.hash`. Для того чтобы браузер "не прыгал" при нажатии по ссылке используйте `preventDefault();`

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var target = $(this).attr('href');

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 250 }, 800, function() {
//Animation complete
 window.location.hash=target;
  });
 

return false;
});
```

```css
.elem:target {
 -webkit-animation: highlight 3s ease-out;
   animation: highlight 3s ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes highlight {
 0% { padding: 7px 0px 9px 0px; background-color: #ffe60b; }
    100% { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
}
@keyframes highlight {
 0% { padding: 7px 0px 9px 0px;   background: #ffd2a3;}
 100% { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#test">Ссыль</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="test" class="elem" style="background:red">#test</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

> UPD

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
var target = $(this).attr('href');
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 250 }, 800);

  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.hash=target;
  },100);


return false;
});
```

Comment: Оно получается в браузере когда на кнопку нажимаешь, начинает отсчет от начала браузере, а если без window.location.hash=target; то получается плавно переходит к якорью, онлайн редакторе это не видно.

Comment: $('a[href^="#"]').bind("click", function(e){
    var anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 250 }, 750);
    e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: это другой код. может он поможет?

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko если вы о "попрыгивании" страницы, я обновил свой ответ

Comment: наверное я тупанул, объясню скрипт типа должен после нажатия на ссылку спускаться *плавно* к якорью, а вобщем получилось что он работает как обчный якорь без скрипта. инными словами плавно не спускается к заданному месту. http://jsfiddle.net/j9knzuh1/47/

Comment: Можете попробовать установить window.location.hash=target; после строки анимации(до return false;) или же установить в самой функции animate(пример показал в ответе)

Comment: все делает так, но теперь оно подтягивает началу!.. вся задумка скрипта теряется опять. как же быть?

Comment: а может просто добавлять клас дополнительный?

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko я проверил работу кода у себя, всё норм, плавно поднимается. Вы проверили у себя или только в jsfiddle смотрите?

Comment: @Aresen да все работает, но он начинает прилипать к верху после нажтии, хотя плавно опускается (там же стоит top - 250 что бы отступ был)

Comment: У вас что то не то )) Ну можете попробовать  установить хеш через доли секунды, дополнил ответ

Comment: бинго, это оно вот так именно я хотел, после UPD)))))))))
Благодарю вас))